# the usage of ' ' and " " in defining string variables

Tags: python

In Python,sometimes I see the string variable using `' '` to define it; sometimes I see the string variable using `" "` to define it.

For instance, it seems to me that both of the followings work

```
file_to_read = os.path.join(path, 'file.txt')

file_to_read = os.path.join(path, "file.txt")
```

My question is that are `' '`and `" "` totally interchangeble?

Comment: Yes. In terms of creating strings they are. However you can nest quotes of different types, but not quotes of the same types.

Comment: Yes and no. Mostly yes, but inside double quotes you have to escape double quotes, inside single quotes you have to escape single quotes. Then there are "triple" quotes than can act as multi-line strings. Try reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in python single quote(') and double quotes (") are totally interchangeable. (Bear in mind, for either, you have to escape the quotes that you surround the string by)

However a common practice is to surround the string that will be displayed to user in double quotes and other "internal" strings in single quotes

Comment: @JohnColeman They are not the same thing because you can not have nested quotes of the same type without escaping them with `\\` first.